# How to limit number of rows can be store in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I need to **limit the number of rows can be insert** in a MySQL Table to 10 only. I need to implement this from MySQL only i.e without using any programming language.

I have created a table with implementing *`MAX_ROWS = 10`* but its not working.

Please check these screenshots.

[image: Check this Screen Shot for Alter Table MAX_ROWS = 10]

[image: Table Properties]

I'm very confused how to do this. If someone will provide me the solution, that would be really helpful for me.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't do screenshots. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It depends on what you want to do when someone tries to insert the 11th row. You could use a ```before insert``` trigger to check for the number of existing rows and abort the insert when there are ten rows.

Comment: The MAX rows you refer to isn't a limit on the number of rows, it is used when creating the DB files as a guide for how to store data and reserve space.

Comment: That said, I would do this one of two ways: Either insert 10 rows and then only allow updates, or handle the insertion logic within the query itself.

Comment: How about auto incremented int key column with constraint < 11?

Comment: @Strawberry Can you explain me in detail? Please explain me second method, ie. how to handle the insertion logic within the query itself?

Comment: @user5226582 Please explain MySQL Query. Lets say I have a table named 'test' with 'id' column with auto increment attribute. How can I limit to max 3?

Comment: What is the use of this table? What do you want to do with the records comes after provided limit?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Please provide me the MySQL Query.

Comment: @money The purpose of this table is just I want to provide some offers to First 10 users only and after 10 users, automatically user registration should be stop.

Comment: @ShubhamKumarRohit [SQL CHECK Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

Comment: Even in that case, you can let the customers register and while providing some offer, just order by your result set based on their registration time and put a limit on the result set.

Comment: If you really don't want to insert into your table, use CHECK constraint or select number of records before inserting or you can also keep the count in separate table.

Comment: @money Can you provide me the mysql query for Check constraint for limiting to 10 only?

Comment: @ShubhamKumarRohit, i have tried using check constraint but it seems to be ignored.
This is what Mysql doc says: 
CHECK

The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 1.8.2.3, “Foreign Key Differences”.

Comment: If you want to prevent registrations after some limit, that should be done in your application code, not in MySQL. For instance, when number 11 comes to your site, they shouldn't have to fill out the form to find out they can't register. Your application should present some message instead of the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no such inbuilt functionality providede by MySQL. One solution is that you can create trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT ON your_table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT;

    SELECT count(*) INTO cnt FROM your_table_name;

    IF cnt = 10 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You can store only 10 records.';
    END IF;
END;
```

Try above trigger on your table. Replace your table_name with **your_table_name**.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As check constraint does not seems to work with MySql. You can try creating a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` on your table and set `NEW.column` value as `NULL` for some not nullable column to break the insert statement.

```
Ex:  
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    col1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(255),
);  

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_before_trig BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable) > 3 THEN
    SET NEW.id = NULL;
END IF;
END;
$$
```

Now try to insert records in mytable, it will ignore 4th records by throwing an error.

Comment: Or, you know, use a signal to abort properly with a decent error message? One day someone decides to make this column nullable -> code breaks, nobody knows why.

Comment: @fancyPants Please provide me the MySql Query for above table 'mytable'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea...:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY  
,val char(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

INSERT INTO my_table (val) SELECT 'b' FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) < 5;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 | b   |
|  2 | b   |
|  3 | b   |
|  4 | b   |
|  5 | b   |
+----+-----+
```