# Limiting the number of data insertion in mysql database table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I am making a localhost website (html, css, js, php and mysql). In that website there is a panel for Appointment. In the appointment section I have created a form asking for appointment date and appointment slot(morning, afternoon and evening).
Here I want to add a condition that for each date there can be at most 10 entries per slot., i.e., for ex: Date: 02-11-2018, morning slot-10 appointment, afternoon slot-10 appointment and evening slot-10 appointment.

Please help me as I am confused, whether I have to do some thing in my database table or in code section(simple html form) to achieve desired functionality.

I got a little bit similar post but the solution provided there didn't helped me. [Solution available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073861/how-to-limit-number-of-rows-can-be-store-in-mysql-table)

In the solution there is two problem for me:
1- In my localhost/phpmyadmin ->db table -> trigger section, when I'm inserting same code it showing error. 
[image: Trigger code i inserted][image: error displaying]

2- In the solution link it is checking if the db table has 10 entries or not but in my case what i have to do is that on a particular date(which is selected from calendar) there can to 10 entries in each column (morning, afternoon and evening) and display list full when any of the column gets full and we try to insert into the same.

Comment: A fifth choice is to build the logic into the query itself

Answer (score 0):

Four choices come to mind.  The first is to do all the checks in the application.  Feasible, but not what you are asking.

The second is to write database triggers for `insert` and `update`.  These would reject any additional appointments after the first 10.

The third would be to have 10 columns, one for each appointment slot.

A fourth choice would be to pre-populate a calendar table with the slots in separate rows.  You would then update the slot that is needed.

I'm definitely not a fan of the third choice, but I include it to answer your question.

I would tend to go for the fourth or first option.

Comment: Someone please help.